# Linear Algebra - Invariant Subspaces in 2-dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

How do I find 2-dimensional subspaces that are invariant subspace of T ?

$T\left(\left[
\begin{matrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
\end{matrix}
\right]\right)
=
\left[\begin{matrix}
2y+z \\ 
-2x+4y+z \\
-2x+2y+3z
\end{matrix}\right]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's  a Axler technic:

Choose $v=(0,0,1) \in \Bbb R^3$. Then the set $\{v,Tv,T^2v,T^3v\}$ is dependent. Actually the set is $$\{(0,0,1),(1,1,3),(5,5,9),(19,19,27)\}$$ Here $$-(0,0,1)+\frac{5}{6}(1,1,3)-\frac{1}{6}(5,5,9)+0(19,19,27)=0$$ That is $$(-1)v+\frac{5}{6}Tv-\frac{1}{6}T^2v+0 T^3 v=0$$ That is $$\left( -\frac{1}{6} T^2+\frac{5}{6}T-I \right) v=0$$ Now it is easy to chech that $\text{span} \{v,Tv\}$ is a  invariant subspace of dimension two!

Comment: Can you explain why you chose the vector $v = (0,0,1)$ and then the line afterward ? aswell as how you got the fractions ?

Comment: See page number 91 and read theorem 5.24 in this [book]( https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://148.206.53.84/tesiuami/S_pdfs/Linear%2520Algebra%2520Done%2520Right.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjoqPyNypLiAhWIf30KHRfKBFQQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw36zAy7BuRknGV2Qzig0EQZ) I just imitate this proof with the easy non zero vector (0,0,1)

Comment: Right but if v is the vector (0,0,1) then wouldn’t Tv = (-2,2,3)?

Comment: How did you get this? For your T , substitute x=y=o and z=1 to get (1,1,3)

Comment: I thought T is the matrices (0, 2, 1),(-2,4,1),(-2,2,3)

Comment: My answer based only on the transformation mentioned in the OP

Comment: The link to my book Linear Algebra Done Right in one of the comments by Chinnapparaj R is a link to an unauthorized copy of the old second edition of the book. The newer third edition contains many improvements.

Comment: @SheldonAxler: Sir.... Actually the book link is freely available in online.  Also by  mentioning other author book without permission is a wrong behaviour, I agree. But I love your proof and its consequences. Thats why I'm mentioning this in comment. Anyway, SORRY for that!

Comment: ........and THANKS for the wonderful book sir!

Answer (score 1):

here's some hint.

I think you can easily find the matrix expression of the given map.

and then try to find eigenvectors. since eigenspaces are T-invariant, you'd find 2-dimensional subspace.

Comment: So I just tried what you said, I got a cubic, haven't solved it yet, but once I find the roots / values, I add both the eigenspaces together so that it'll be 
$e_{x}+ke_{y}, e_{y}+ke_{z}$ and $e_{x}+ke_{z}$ ?

Comment: Oh I had some mistakes... you'll get one multiple root (with multiplicity 2) when you solve the characteristic equation. so you can just take the corresponding eigenspace.

Comment: as I mentioned, this case doesn't have to direct sum the eigenspaces. (sorry for confusing you.) but in case that you have to, remind that each eigenvector is independent. (this is why you can take a eigenbasis for a matrix)

Comment: so I got eigenvalues, 2,2 and 3

I then get matrices


$e_{2} = \left(\begin{matrix}
-2&2&1\\
-2&2&1\\
-2&2&1
\end{matrix}\right)$
&
$e_{3}\left(\begin{matrix}
-3&2&1\\
-2&1&1\\
-2&2&0
\end{matrix}\right)$

Comment: you almost there. the multiple root 2 means there are two eigenvectors corresponding to. all you have to do is find them, and then the span of them will be your answer.

Comment: What do you mean by that ? do I just Row reduce -> 
$\left(\begin{matrix}
1&-1&\frac{-1}{2}\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{matrix}\right)$

$z = t, y = s$

therefore $x = s + \frac{1}{2}t$

Comment: so the matrix $ e_2 $ you computed is $ T - 2I $ right? considering the definition of eigenvector, your next step is finding the null space of it. actually, the null space itself is the space what you find.

Comment: $\left[\begin{matrix}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}\\
x_{3}
\end{matrix}\right]
=
$s\left[\begin{matrix}1\\1\\0\end{matrix}\right]+t\left[\begin{matrix}0\\\frac{1}{2}\\1\end{matrix}\right]$

Comment: if you want a explicit form, span( (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 2) ) is a simple one.

Comment: It asks me to find 3 2-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Do I just let the span be 3 different spans such as '1((1,1,0),(1,0,2))', '2((1,1,0),(1,0,2))' & '3((1,1,0),(1,0,2))' ?

or would I give spans of eivenvectors 2, 3 and 6(2*3)

Comment: well, if you need three subspaces, remind that the three eigenvectors form a basis for the map $ T $. so choose two among them, and then the space they span will be 2-dimensional, T-invariant. there are 3 ways to choose 2 eigenvectors among 3 of them, so I think you finished the problem.

Comment: Can you clarify ? Choose two of the eigenvectors will be the same, so v_{1} = v_{2}$. I can choose $v_{1} ^& v_{2}$, $v_{2} &v_{3}$ and $v_{1}&v_{3}$ but wouldn't $v_{2} &v_{3}$ and $v_{1}&v_{3}$ be the same ?

Comment: you'll get eigenvector $ v_3 = (1, 1, 1) $ for eigenvalue 3. if span($ v_1, v_3 $) = span($ v_2, v_3 $), $ v_2 $ can be represented by a linear combination of $ v_1 $ and $ v_3 $, but this doesn't happen since {$ v_1, v_2, v_3 $} forms a basis. they are independent.

Comment: Ahhhh so span{(1,1,1),(1,1,0)}, span{(1,1,1),(1,0,2)} and span{(1,1,0),(1,0,2)} are the 3 Two dimensional vector spaces

Comment: that's right, you've got it.

Comment: Okay thank you a lot!

Comment: @JCheong No need to solve a cubic to find the eigenvalues. You can find eigenvalues $3$ and $2$ by inspection: All of the row sums are $3$ and subtracting the last row from the previous one gives $2(0,1,-1)$. You get the remaining eigenvalue “for free” by examining the trace.